# Backup restore db from sql server 2008 r2 to 2008

Tags: sql-server

I need to backup and restore a db on sql server 2008R2 to sql server 2008. The backup file is not compatible this way. The other option that i found is to generate scripts that include data. Will the inserts succeed since i have the db normalised with lots of foreign keys?

Is there any other reliable approach?

Comment: I have used the "generate scripts with data" option several times and it hasn't failed me yet. I think it will copy in the data first before applying constraints, not unlike PostgreSQL's plain text backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noted: the direct restore **cannot** be done. SQL Server has never been backwards compatible in the sense of restoring a database from a newer version back to a server with an older version.

What you could do is use generated INSERT statements (using SSMS directly, or a handy add-in such as [SSMS Toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolpack.com)), or you could use a good SQL DIFF tool like [Red-Gate SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to compare your two databases (even from a backup file, in the pro version!) and update one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not allow downgrading you can create a backup of your database in SQL Server 2008R2 instance and use third party tools, ApexSQL Diff and ApexSQL Data Diff to restore the backup an older version of SQL Server.

You can read detailed explanation of the process in this article: [Restoring SQL Server database backup to an older version of SQL Server](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/restore-sql-server-database-backup-to-older-version-of-sql-server/)

Hope this helps

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the export data wizard. Right click on the Database in SSMS, Tasks, Export Data and copy all or whichever objects you need.

Answer (score 0):

Backward compatibility is not available in SQL server 2008 R2 . One solution is that the database script generate and run the desired server.