# Can we restore database backup of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 Express 

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, database-backups

I have a database backup in "SQL Server 2008 R2", Can i store this database backup in "SQL 2008 Express" ?

Anyone who have knowledge about SQL-2008 kindly share to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backup restore db from sql server 2008 r2 to 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812099/backup-restore-db-from-sql-server-2008-r2-to-2008)

Comment: This [has been asked (and answered!) a great many times already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=restore+backup+2008+R2+onto+2008) - you should **SEARCH** first before asking the same question yet again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, you cannot do this.

There is no way, no method, no hack, no workaround, no trick to get a backup from a more recent version of SQL Server back into an older version.

It just doesn't work - it's not supported.

You'll need to synchronize your structure using some kind of SQL diff tool, and possibly your data by exporting and importing, e.g. via the "Data Export / Import" wizard or some custom way.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, i am searching over this.

Answer (score 3):

No and 'yes'.

A backup (.bak) is not possible, nor is copying .mdf over but you can downgrade.

You could go back to 2005 if you wish to.

I found this information which runs you through it the easy way.

[How to Downgrade SQL Server Database](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Downgrade_SQL_Server_Database_P1.html)

Direct link: http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Downgrade_SQL_Server_Database_P1.html

TIP: Use Microsoft OLEDB connector to destination instead of the native client and you should avoid any errors in the transfer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is impossible, you just have to get creative :)

- Install an instance of SQL 2008 R2 on one machine and SQL 2008 on another
- Open SQL Server Management Studio R2
- Select your source Database
- Select Tasks>Generate Scripts.
- Select 'Script entire database and all database objects', press 'Next'
- Select 'Save to File' and click on the 'Advanced' button
- Select 'Script for Server Version' and select the version you want: 200/2005/2008
- Select 'Type of data to Script' and select Schema/Data/both
- Click 'OK',Next and do it!
- Copy the resulting file to the target machine with SQL 2008 [or whatever]
- Log onto your SQL Management Studio and open the copied .sql file... be aware that there may be limitations on the file size.
  There may also be issues with the order that the .SQL file inserts the data into the target database and if there are FK constraints in place, this could be an issue.... simply re-order the insert lists.
  Once the .sql file is organized, parse it [just to sure], and then execute.

Let me clarify a little on these directions.

On the SQL Management Tools be logged into both the old and the new server if possible.This makes these steps even easier.

So, start with the source server, right click on the database and script it.  There is one option called ‘Script Data’ that is off by default, we set it to true so the script will include inserts for all of the data.  We choose to script the tables, views, indexes and keys (and triggers … not sure if you use any of those).  I also did  not mess with the users, since that is problematic.  It is easier to create the user by hand once on the local SQL server and give them permissions to the dbs.

Then script the DB to a file.

Then select the local SQL server and add the database by hand, then open up the script file and execute it under the new database, all the tables, data, indexes, etc came over just fine.  Setup the user permission and you are golden.